# SQL Select Distinct with ints and varchars

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I have a query which returns a number of ints and varchars.

I want the result Distinct but by only one of the ints.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        t.TaskID ,
        td.[TestSteps]
FROM    SOX_Task t
snip
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What would you expect the output to look like?  You can just SELECT DISTINCT the int column?

Comment: This is a very vague question - could you provide more detail about what you want to do, and what database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the result Distinct but by only one of the ints.

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.taskid
  FROM SOX_TASK t
```

...will return a list of unique taskid values - there will not be any duplicates.

If you want to return a specific value, you need to specify it in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM SOX_TASK t
 WHERE t.taskid = ?
```

That will return all the rows with the specific `taskid` value.  If you want a distict list of the values associated with the taskid value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
  FROM SOX_TASK t
 WHERE t.taskid = ?
```

`GROUP BY` is another means of getting distinct/unique values, and it's my preference to use, but in order to use `GROUP BY` we need to know the columns in the table and what grouping you want.

Answer (score 3):

DISTINCT doesn't work that way ... it ensures that entire rows are not duplicated. Besides, if it did, how would it decide which values should appear in other columns?

What you probably want to do here is a GROUP BY on the column you want to be distinct, and then apply an appropriate aggregate operator to the other columns to get the values you want (eg. MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG, etc).

For example, the following returns a distinct list of task IDs with the maximum number of steps for that task. That may not be exactly what you want, but it should give you the general idea.

```
SELECT t.TaskID, MAX(t.TestSteps)
FROM SOX_Task t
GROUP BY t.TaskID
```